# Cannot make echo in a public function

Tags: php, echo

I am new at php and making exercises.

I write `echo` in a function but nothing happens, no result.

```
class Glass {
    public function height($h) {
        return $h;
        echo "The height is: empty $h" . "<br>";
    }
}
```

When I try to `echo` outside the function, I get a result:

```
echo "The base circle area is : $a";
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You are using `echo` after `return`. It will never get to the `echo` statement.

Comment: ah ok... so return is like exit(). thanks @b0s3

Comment: `return` is not exactly like `exit`. `return` will "end" the *function* execution, but `exit` will actually exit the php script which is running.

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? It's a proper question with code which isn't behaving like the OP expects it to.

Comment: *"If called from within a function, the **return** statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call"* -- http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php

Comment: thank you guys. I got something.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `echo` is after `return`. At `return`, the function "ends", nothing further will be executed.

To see the `echo`, adjust your code so it is *before* the `return`:

```
public function height($h) {
    echo "The height is: empty $h" . "<br>";
    return $h;
}
```